# ng click function not working in angularJS controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my code, Actually when I click on function but not showing alert and not getting error in console. So please tell me how to do.

HTML Code

```
 <li class="has-megamenu" ng-click="homepage()" ><a ><span >Home</span></a>
 </li>
```

app.js

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
$scope.homepage = function(){
    alert('hi');
}});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** You have to add `ng-app = "app"`

**Second** You have to add `ng-controller = "myController"`

**Final**
Please check the updated code:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
$scope.homepage = function(){
    alert('hi');
}});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body ng-app = "app">
    <div ng-controller = "myController">
      <li class="has-megamenu" ng-click="homepage()" ><a ><span >Home</span></a>
       </li>
     <div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 6):

There can be two reasons

1- Not using `ng-app` directive in the root element of your application.

2- You have not defined `ng-controller` properly.

Please follow following working code.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
      $scope.homepage = function() {
        alert('hi');
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <ul>
      <li class="has-megamenu" ng-click="homepage()"><a><span >Home</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```